# Siamese model not learning anything, always encodes the image into a vector of zeros

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, similarity

I am trying to train a siamese model to predict if words written in two images are same or not. Apart from this model should also be able to differentiate between the writing of two people. The problem is similar to the signature verification problem.

My base network looks like this:

```
def create_base_network_signet(input_shape):
    '''Base Siamese Network'''

    seq = Sequential()
    seq.add(Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(7,7), strides=2, input_shape= input_shape, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(BatchNormalization())
    seq.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(2, 2)))

    seq.add(Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(7,7), strides=1, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(BatchNormalization())
    seq.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
    seq.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))

    seq.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=1, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=1, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.3))
    seq.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))

    seq.add(Conv2D(384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(BatchNormalization())
    seq.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=2))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.3))
    seq.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1)))

    seq.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(2,2), strides=1, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.3))

    seq.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))
    seq.add(Dense(1024, W_regularizer=l2(0.0005), activation='relu', init='glorot_uniform'))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.4))

    seq.add(Dense(128, W_regularizer=l2(0.0005), activation='relu', init='glorot_uniform')) # softmax changed to relu

    return seq
```

Final model(for contrastive loss):

```
base_network = create_base_network_signet(input_shape)
input_a = Input(shape=(input_shape), name="first")
input_b = Input(shape=(input_shape), name="second")

processed_a = base_network(input_a)
processed_b = base_network(input_b)

distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance, output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([processed_a, processed_b])

model = Model(input=[input_a, input_b], output=distance)
```

Apart from this model, I have also tried other simpler models as base model. I have also tried to train models like VGG16 and Inception as base model. While training all these models I have encountered the same problem. Models end up learning to encode the input image into a vector of zeros.

I have tried triplet loss and contrastive loss to train the models. Both end up having the same problem of predicting zeros. The contrastive loss function is taken from `keras` tutorials. And triplet loss is defined as:

```
def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, alpha = 0.5):
    anchor, positive, negative = y_pred[0], y_pred[1], y_pred[2]
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), axis=-1)
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), axis=-1)
    basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), alpha)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0))

    return loss
```

I also want to mention that when I train my model using `binary_crossentropy` loss function. The model starts to learn encodings. But, after the accuracy of around 82%, the accuracy stops improving, but the loss keeps on decreasing.

This is what output encoding looks like in case of triplet loss and contrastive loss:

[image: output of model]

My training data looks like this:

[image: data example]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in one of my Siamese networks trained with triplet loss. The trick for me was to remove `tf.reduce_sum()` part from `loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0))` line. My relevant snippet of the triplet loss code is as follows.

```
# distance between the anchor and the positive
pos_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor-positive),axis=1)

# distance between the anchor and the negative
neg_dist = K.sum(K.square(anchor-negative),axis=1)

# compute loss
basic_loss = pos_dist-neg_dist+alpha
loss = K.maximum(basic_loss,0.0)
```

Finally when you compile the model do it as follows.

`model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=triplet_loss)`

I believe the `reduce_sum()` part is taken care by keras in training, when `triplet_loss` is given as the `loss`.

Try this and see if it helps.

Comment: So, yesterday I modified the architecture of my base model and added a few more convolutional layers. Now, the model with triplet loss not giving zeros as encoding. It has also started to learn to keep the distance between the anchor and positive low, whereas keep distance between anchor and negative relatively high. But, still results are not good because the range of output is variable.

Comment: Eg, this is how results look like right now.-

**Triplet 1**--> distance(a, n) = 0.34774 and distance(a, p) = 0.028473.

**Triplet 2**--> distance(a, n) = 0.044774 and distance(a, p) = 0.018473.

**Triplet 3**--> distance(a, n) = 0.46774 and distance(a, p) = 0.18473.

Should I train the model for more epochs? Also when I trained the new model on contrastive loss, It was still giving 0 as output encoding. I will also try your suggestions.

Comment: Bro, I have tried everything you said. But it is still not working. I am still having the problem of zero encodings.